# Extract second section of string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I will have always an string like this:

```
"/FirstWord/ImportantWord/ThirdWord"
```

How can I extract the `ImportantWord`? Words can contain at most one space and they are separated by `forward slash`like I put above, for example:

```
"/Folder/Second Folder/Content"
"/Main folder/Important/Other Content"
```

I always want to get the second word(`Second Folder` and `Important` considering above examples)

Comment: Use the [String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create an array of values split by the `/` character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
string ImportantWord = path.Split('/')[2]; // Index 2 will give the required word
```

Comment: That will return `"FirstWord"` not `"ImportantWord"` because the first item in the array is an empy string (the `RemoveEmptyEntries` option is required)

Answer (score 2):

I hope you need not to use the `String.Split` option either with specific characters or with some regular expressions. Since the inputs are well qualified paths to a directory you can use `Directory.GetParent` method of the System.IO.Directory class, which will give you the parent Directory as DirectoryInfo. From that you can take the Name of Directory which will be the required text.

You can use like this :

```
string pathFirst = "/Folder/Second Folder/Content";
string pathSecond = "/Main folder/Important/Other Content";

string reqWord1 = Directory.GetParent(pathFirst ).Name; // will give you Second Folder
string reqWord2 = Directory.GetParent(pathSecond).Name; // will give you Important
```

Additional note: The method `Directory.GetParent` can be nested if you need to get a name in another level.

Answer (score 2):

Also you may try this:

```
var stringValue = "/FirstWord/ImportantWord/ThirdWord";
var item = stringValue.Split('/').Skip(2).First();   //item: ImportantWord
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve this. The simplest one is using [String.split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Char delimiter = '/';
String[] substrings = value.Split(delimiter);
String secondWord = substrings[1];
```

(you may want to do some input check to make sure the input is in the right format or else you will get some exception)

Other way is using [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) when the pattern is simple `/`

If you are sure this is a path you can use other answer mention here